# Open "Show available networks" panel from command line or windows message

Tags: c#, windows, wifi, settings

i just signed up to ask this question.

I want to open the "Show available networks" Panel on the notifications area from the command line or by window message / winapi. (I want to open it from inside a C# Desktop App)

I have found `ms-settings:network-wifi` but this is not the correct window but the Panel can be opened from this window as well.

Target system is Windows 10 LTS 1607 Enterprise.

Can anyone help me or hint me on how to get the command?
Thanks in advance and best regards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well after some research i have found the correct command to launch the "available networks" flyout from command line:

```
explorer.exe ms-availablenetworks:
```

[Post on tenforums.com with many other commands](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/78108-app-commands-list-windows-10-a.html)

Hope this helps someone else as well :)

Cheers

Comment: This doesn't seem to work 2 months on. It simply returns a pop-up saying "You'll need a new app to open this: ms-availablenetworks"

Did this work for you?

Comment: Works perfectly for me on different systems. What system do you use? Could it be possible there are system restrictions / group policys applied to your system.

Comment: I'm on Windows 10 Pro. Haven't really looked into group policies, so that could be a factor

Comment: FYI for Googlers: you need to add the `:` at the end--it is *not* a typo.